# How can I select and Deselect all items by checkbox in dynamically added check _list_box in c#?

Tags: c#, winforms

I wanted to do select/ deselect with one checkbox. I have tried to get the index of the selected item. I haven't been able to get this, so I tried to change the name of the box. Still no success.

```
foreach (var item in DATAsetname_INIlist)
{
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add(item);
}
if (checkedListBox2.Items.Count != 0)
{
    checkedListBox2.Items.Add("Select all");
}

private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (checkedListBox2.Items.Count != 0)
    {

          if (checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Select all")
          {
                 for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
                 {
                    checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                 }
                 string changed = "Deselect all";
                 checkedListBox2.SelectedItem =changed;
          }
          if (checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Deselect all")
          {
            for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++)
            {
                checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, false);
            }
            string changed = "Select all";
            checkedListBox2.SelectedItem = changed;
          }
    }
}
```

can you please help on this ? thank you

Comment: Is this webforms or WPF, etc? Also [whats' not working, etc.](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Comment: it is Windows application.  for me with  check mark  selectall checkbox I can able to select all items but with deselect selectall  checkbox i am not able to deslect all iteams

Comment: yes winforms sorry wrongly written due to checking correction in question

Comment: Ok, now we've got the right tags, I've improved your english and formatted your code. The question is **still** not clear I'm afraid. so try and explain what exactly you want, what you've tried, why that didn't work, etc. Basically [follow the advise here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: one thing I see is that upon successfully setting the item to "Deselect all" it will then immediately jump to the next if statement and find that it is == "Select all" so there might be an issue there. But I think the big thing will be that you won't even trigger if you were to check and uncheck without first moving off that line.

Comment: Actually to set it to deselect all triggers a selectedindexchanged and you will get a null reference exception on `if (checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Select all")` because SelectedItem will be null

Answer (score 3):

Have done quick exercise. Please modify your code accordingly.

```
/// <summary>
/// Check all check boxes and vice versa
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender"></param>
/// <param name="e"></param>
private void ChkSelectAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Declare your checkedListBox2 count
    iCount = checkedListBox2.Items.Count;
    if (sender != null)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= iCount; i++)
        {
            CheckBox ck = null;
            Control[] chkTest = this.Controls.Find("chkDrive" + i, true);

            if (chkTest.Length > 0)
            {
                if (chkSelectAll.Checked)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < chkTest.Length; j++)
                    {
                        ck = (CheckBox)chkTest[j];
                        ck.Checked = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < chkTest.Length; j++)
                    {
                        ck = (CheckBox)chkTest[j];
                        ck.Checked = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }            
}
```

Answer (score 1):

can you try this.

```
try
        {
            checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged -= checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
            if (checkedListBox1.Items.Count != 0)
            {
                if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Select all")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, true);
                    }
                    string changed = "Deselect all";
                    checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex] = changed;
                }
                else if (checkedListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Deselect all")
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false);
                    }
                    string changed = "Select all";
                    checkedListBox1.Items[checkedListBox1.SelectedIndex] = changed;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
        finally
        {
            checkedListBox1.SelectedIndexChanged += checkedListBox1_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

When i work with c# i had litle simillar problem in my case was enought was to replace if(string==string) by string.equals(string)

Btw few questions:

1. `checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString()` what is value in here where comparing?
2. Does your listener work at all?
3. Not better way to check which checkBox is taken comparing sender in switch?
4. How u declare `checkedListBox2`
5. By `checkedListBox2.Items.Add(item);` i suspect u create checkBoxes by hand can u show it? meybe something is there wrong

This part added after Lian comment

```
        foreach(var item in DATAsetname_INIlist)
    {
        checkedListBox2.Items.Add(item);
    }
    if (checkedListBox2.Items.Count != 0) {
        checkedListBox2.Items.Add("Select all");
    }

    private void checkedListBox2_SelectedIndexChanged (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (checkedListBox2.Items.Count != 0 && checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().equals("Select all")) {
            changeStateOfSelectedItem("Deselect all", true);
        } else if (checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString().equals("Deselect all")) {
            changeStateOfSelectedItem("Select all", false);
        }
    }

    private void changeStateOfSelectedItem (String state, bolean stateToReplace){
    for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox2.Items.Count; i++) {
        checkedListBox2.SetItemChecked(i, stateToReplace);
    }
    string changed = state;
    checkedListBox2.SelectedItem = changed;
```

Comment: This is a list of question not an answer to the question. Please only add answers that actually answer the question. If you want some clarification do so in comments

Comment: 1. checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() when you checked or unchecked any item in the checkboxlist it will come here.                                                                         3. Didn't find any better way                                                                                              5. yes creating dynamically depending upon list(DATAsetname_INIlist) it will add in the checkboxlist.   and for select it is working properly for only deselect it is not working

Comment: Lian read more carefull meybe u will see i wrote also posible resolution. But for case it didin't work i ask question for get more information. Compare string and string by == not always is good result. Now back to case:

I suspect changeing == on equals not work. Btw you answered only for last question 

If not working only deselect in this function probobly is something wrong with this condition


if (checkedListBox2.SelectedItem.ToString() == "Deselect all")

1. change if statment to use String.equals(StringSecond)
2. check does your condition is correct

Answer (score -1):

If this is C# based, windows application.

Search form collection and find all check box on form, using for each.

**Code**

```
foreach(CheckBox item in Form.Control)
{ 
    Item.Checked=true;
}
```

**For check list box**

```
for(int i;I<checklistbox.items.count;I++)
{ 
 checklistbox.SetItemChecked(I,true);
}
```

Comment: yes I tried this but how to deselect all but with same checkbox

Comment: This is working my side. Maybe you required something else. Can you explain your issue

Comment: It’s working on my system. Can you explain what’s you requirement?

Comment: actually I am filling checkboxlist dynamically also select all check box . When i am check select all button I have beeen able to select all other element. but same when I have doing  unchecked select all button not able to do deselect of other element